# Sorting by maximum value and display a different column than the one used for sorting

Tags: awk

I have data in a file that looks like :

```
id Name     records 
1  joe      3
1  james    4
1  jacky    4
2  mike     10
2  mat      8
2  peter    10
3  bob      3
3  alice    1
3  wis      1
```

All records with the same id belongs to one person but the names may be different. I need to find the id with maximum records . In the above eg id 2 has records equal to 10+8+10 = 28 and is the maximum value as compared to other ids.
So the result of my query should be any one of the given names i.e either mike or mat or peter,I need to this using awk;

I tried the following:

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in arr){if(arr[i]>max) max=arr[i] ; name=i} } END {print name}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- you aren't ignoring the header row
- you aren't saving the name (`$2`) anywhere,
- you have 2 `END`s.

I think you want this:

```
awk 'NR>1{count[$1]+=$3;name[$1]=$2;} END{for(i in count){if(count[i]>m){m=count[i]; n=name[i]}};print m,n}' file

28 peter
```